# soapUI - Use WSDL from Websphere Message Broker

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui, messagebroker

I'm doing a project with WebSphere Message Broker which results in 2 BAR files. One the client and the other the server. Both are deployed in a broker in a remote location (a server upstairs). The WSDL that the server flow uses is inside an Message Set Project. Here is the wsdl structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI at http://jax-ws.dev.java.net. RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.1.3.1-hudson-749-SNAPSHOT. -->
<definitions targetNamespace="http://ws.interact.bytesw.com/" name="TvPagaInteractWebService" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.interact.bytesw.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <types> 
    <xsd:schema>
      <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.interact.bytesw.com/" schemaLocation="TvPagaInteractWebServiceService.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
  </types>
  <message name="ejecutarTransaccion">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:ejecutarTransaccion"/>
  </message>
  <message name="ejecutarTransaccionResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:ejecutarTransaccionResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="consultarOperacion">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:consultarOperacion"/>
  </message>
  <message name="consultarOperacionResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:consultarOperacionResponse"/>
  </message>
  <message name="consultarServicio">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:consultarServicio"/>
  </message>
  <message name="consultarServicioResponse">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:consultarServicioResponse"/>
  </message>
  <portType name="TvPagaInteractWebService">
    <operation name="ejecutarTransaccion">
      <input message="tns:ejecutarTransaccion"/>
      <output message="tns:ejecutarTransaccionResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="consultarOperacion">
      <input message="tns:consultarOperacion"/>
      <output message="tns:consultarOperacionResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="consultarServicio">
      <input message="tns:consultarServicio"/>
      <output message="tns:consultarServicioResponse"/>
    </operation>
  </portType>
  <binding name="TvPagaInteractWebServicePortBinding" type="tns:TvPagaInteractWebService">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="ejecutarTransaccion">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="consultarOperacion">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
    <operation name="consultarServicio">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </input>
      <output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </output>
    </operation>
  </binding>
  <service name="TvPagaInteractWebService">
    <port name="TvPagaInteractWebServicePort" binding="tns:TvPagaInteractWebServicePortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
  </service>
</definitions>
```

Once deployed I want to use it from soapUI. But I don't know which endpoint configure it. I've been trying some combinations including the IP and port of the broker connection. But doesn't work, can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your WSDL you have this

```
<service name="TvPagaInteractWebService">
    <port name="TvPagaInteractWebServicePort" binding="tns:TvPagaInteractWebServicePortBinding">
      <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

In REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL goes the address where WMB should bind this particular service so its accesible from the outside

Comment: Yeah, I know. That path it's what I'm looking for. Good news is, I found the correct IP and port combination to access the server, but this appear: "Can't find URL mapping for |/TvPagaInteractWebServiceService/|"

The endpoint I use obviously is http://<server_ip>:<port>/TvPagaInteractWebServiceService, but it doesn't work. Where does WMB have that path defined?

Comment: What's the node suffix? on the other hand, have you tried to access http://[IP]:[Port]/TvPagaInteractWebServiceService?wsdl and see if it works? Also, what exactly you put in the soap address? One last thing, the httpconnector is up right?

Comment: I guess the httpconnector is fine, because I'm getting response from the server. The mapping is the only problem, i guess. I wonder, the http://<ip>:<port>/name pattern, is it right? Because the wsdl is contained in the MSP project. so I thought that between:

http://<ip>:<port>/ and the name, shouldn't be there something more, maybe?

Answering the first question, yes. I tried that pattern (http://[IP]:[Port]/TvPagaInteractWebServiceService?wsdl), says can't find the mapping.

Comment: in the soap address justput http//:ip:port

Comment: Still says that cannot find mapping. "Can't find URL mapping for |/|"

Comment: Hmmm, what does this shows? mqsireportproperties <bkrname> -e <egname> -o HTTPConnector -r

Comment: Apparently, it fails to initialize sorry. An error appears indicating termination of the program. Is it because it's remote or something?

Comment: Ok, words short. Tested the same command in the server machine. Says something that is not properly configured for that command, and to do something with mqsiprofile, or something. It's something o__o

Comment: Ok, I feel a little dumb right now. The broker was not on. Here's the result of the command (It was long, so i put it in pastebin):
http://pastebin.com/ZwibHLkc

Sorry for that u__u

Comment: Tried on browser and on soapUI. Still the same. Can't find the mapping on soapUI and on browser "Unsupported Method: GET".

Comment: thats odd, switch your request type to POST

Answer (score 0):

The port which the broker is listening on is a property of the listener. The SOAP nodes use the EG level embedded listener by default so you can find this by executing the command:

mqsireportproperties  -e  -o HTTPConnector -r

This port can be found in this information but also the current URL registrations are displayed.

The path that the service is bound to is defined by the URL property on the SOAP node itself which you can find from the toolkit.